# where do the constructor function arguments come from if it is not on remix

Tags: solidity, remix

I am reading this smart contract and I wonder where are those arguments come from. Or should I pass in those arguments when I deploy my smart contracts through remix? Thanks in advance.

[image: smart contract]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When deploy the smart contract via Remix, there's a place to input the constructor params.

[image: remix params]

If you deploy via script like hardhat, then you can pass the params via the deploy method:

```
const router = await QuickswapRouter.deploy(factoryAddress, MUMBAI_WMATIC);
```

Comment: Ok I get it. Those parameters for the constructor come from the contract owner, passing them while deploying?